# How to access a specific object already displayed in template?

Tags: python, django

I am creating a django view that that does the action of liking a picture. However, the issue I am having is I can not seem to access the id of the specific picture the user liked. I have tried to do it through url patterns but i got the error "like_photo() takes 2 arguments one given" when feedclass_id is passed in the like_photo view. Having said that, I would rather process the information without any change of the url. I am also getting the error "get() returned more than one FeedClas -- it returned 9"!  when the pk is changed to 1 for example. The user has uploaded 9 photos by the way. So the main question is, how can work this code to update the likes of each individual photo when the submit button is clicked.
 My code is below.

```
class FeedClas(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='folder')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    user_posted = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="phot"
        )

    num_comments = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    date_pub = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_liked = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

HERE IS MY VIEW:

```
def like_photo(request):
    user = request.user.id
    #get all photos that belong to this user
    photos = Feedclas.objects.get(user_posted_id=user)
    photo = Feedclas.objects.get(pk="here is where I am having the trouble")
    if photo.is_liked == False:
        #once user clicks like, boolean field changes value to true,
        #so they do not like same picture twice
        photo.is_liked = True
        photo.likes += 1
        photo.save()
        return  HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('appname:account', args=(photo)))
    #if already liked do not change total likes
    elif photo.is_liked == True:
        photo.likes += 0
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('appname:account', args=(photo)))
```

TEMPLATE:

Each photo instance is being accessed through a for loop. The idea here is that when we submit the form we have an empty heart because liked is False but once it becomes true, the else statement runs and we display a full heart.

```
{% if photo.is_liked == False %}
      <form action= "{% url 'appname:like' %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
      <button type ="submit" class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty"></button>
    </form>
    {% else %}
    <button type ="submit" class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty"></button>
    {% endif %}
```

url pattern:
I gave this view the same url as the main account view, but with a different name and view function to process.
/main/account

```
url(r'^account/$', views.account, name="account"),
```

/url/to/work/with

```
url(r'^account/$', views.like_photo, name="like"),
```

Comment: You've got duplicate URL patterns, which isn't supported. Depending on the order in your `urls.py`, only one of them is active. You also *will* need to pass some identifier for the photo from your "like" form, i.e. the "like" view will most likely need the primary key of the photo as input. Otherwise, the view has no way of knowing the photo.

Comment: @dhke does this mean that one url can not process information from 2 different views?

Comment: Yes. Django has to determine from the URL which view has to handle a request. Currently, it has no way to discern, if `views.account` or `views.like_photo` should be called.

Comment: `get()` can only return one result, but you are asking for all photos for a single user. Just do it in one go: `Feedclas.objects.get(user_posted=user, pk=feedclass_id)` which also saves a database query. Note also there's [`get_object_or_404()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404). And: There's no need to explicitly retrieve the user id, you can toss in the user object into the queryset just fine.

Comment: It is still producing the same error.